# best config for ehcache3 with springboot 2.5.4

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, ehcache

I am going to use Ehcache with Springboot. I just wanted to know what will best configuration while working with high volume of requests.

We may receive more than 30000 req/hour while live. Though in Development we  cannot produce this scenario.

Could you please help me how I can calculate the memory to create a best configuration which shall work perfectly in Prod.

I checked the response size in Postman which is 3-5 kb in Dev, so I have kept the below configuration but not sure how well it will go. We have a memory size of 2GB (in prod we can get 4 GB). ttl is set as 1 hr.

```
<heap>5000</heap>
<offheap unit="MB">100</offheap>
```

Could you please let me know if this will work or not with volume of requests I mentioned for live?

Comment: Did you tried https://jmeter.apache.org/ in order to do volumetric test?

Comment: these tools are not available in client system, so I can not use them

Comment: Maybe you can rephrase your question a bit toward "how to determine the optimal cache size" that might be more relevant for others. Stackoverflow isn't meant to solve a particular setup problem.

Answer (score 1):

Questions for "best" and "perfect" are difficult to answer, in general.

The optimal cache size depends on:

- the data key space
- its distribution
- the response sizes
- the cost and time to regenerate evicted data
- SLAs, e.g. maximum user response times

Your 30000 req/hour may go always to the same data point, so your cache would only need 5kb.

How much heap and off heap cache you configure, also depends on a trade offs between memory and CPU costs and response times.

Even if your dev machine is not fast enough for handling production load, you can still test it with the same access sequences that you have in production. Maybe for one hour production load you need four hours in dev to test your setup.

Another possibility is to reduce your data key space for testing in dev. However it is important that you have a similar key distribution.

Some practical advice:
If you are caching basically a REST response (you mentioned postman), caching inside the application might be not a good choice. Maybe use HTTP based caching between user and application

For optimum caching in production you will need to test and adapt, according what you see in production. Best you start with a bigger machine and bigger cache size in production, then lower the capacity according your hitrates, cost expectations and service levels.